# nginx not forwarding query strings to keycloak

Tags: nginx, keycloak

I've setup nginx and keycloak with docker compose.

nginx.conf includes under location /:

```
proxy_pass http://keycloak:8080;
proxy_set_header Host $http_host;
proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forearded_for;
```

The error seen in keycloak log:

```
type=LOGIN_ERROR,realmId=myrealm, clientId=null, userId=Null, ip address=192.168.128.4, error=invalid_code
```

How do I config nginx to pass the query strings?

Comment: $proxy_add_x_forearded_for;
Is it really like this or is it a typo (> "forearded" instead of "forwarded" ) ?
This could also help: https://github.com/jinnerbichler/keycloak-nginx/blob/master/nginx.conf

Comment: Just a typo. Turns out the issue was a configuration of an openid client and not nginx.